# Can't prevent background image from moving down

Tags: css, image, background

I'm pretty new to HTML, so apologies if I'm doing something really silly.

I've set up some code like this (just a template):

```
 <div id="outer-page">
 <div id="main-page">

    <header>
    <h1 id="title">Jamina's Free Cat-Sitting Service</h1>
    </header>
```

The header is at the very top of the page when I view the site using JSbin. I want to move the whole #main-page down, which I've tried to do using 'margin-top', however, whenever the main page div moves down, the background image moves down with it, causing a gap at the top of the page. Does anyone know why this happening and how I can prevent it?

Thanks in advance,

Steve.

Comment: Could you post the JSbin? It sounds like your background-image is being applied to #main-page and not #outer-page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the [collapsing margins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) feature.

For instance, if your CSS looks like

```css
#outer-page {background:#DDE;}
#main-page {margin-top:2em}
```

the page will look like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sX6eX/).

The solution is to give the outer page a padding, rather than giving the main page a margin:

```css
#outer-page {background:#DDE; padding-top:1em}
```

and that will look like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sX6eX/1/).

(Please note that the main page will also include the margin of the `h1`, so you will need less padding than you would have needed margin; paddings and margins do not collapse together.)

Alternatively, if you really want to have a margin on the main page, you can do this little trick:

```css
#outer-page {background:#DDE; padding-top:1px; margin-top:-1px;}
#main-page {margin-top:2em}
```

resulting in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/sX6eX/2/).
The trick is that even a 1 pixel padding will prevent the margins from collapsing, and we also undo the effect of the 1 pixel padding by using a -1 pixel margin. Net result of 0, but without the collapsing.